# Database Normalisation (1NF 2NF 3NF)

Tags: database, normalization

Currently I'm confused with the whole normalisation thing for databases.

Can anyone help me figure out how to go to 1NF following to 3NF? My 1NF version looks like this though not sure this is correct..:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyzBS.png

The link contains both the UNF and my version of the 1NF table.

Answer (score -1):

Having just looked here for the definitions :) :http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php. 
1nf requires that each row can reliably identified. In your table you do not have a clear primary key. Each row can be identified by flight number and part of the status fields (arrival or departure) and the scheduled time

I can see that your table violates 2nf because your status fields seem to contain multiple pieces of information and is not a of a single data type,ie it tells you 2 pieces of information: arrival/departure  and the time. There is also an implied value in the actual status of 'Cancelled' which would not have an associated time.

3nf eliminates dependencies between fields that are not part of the primary key, in your case I would point the finger at the from and to fields: their values could be part of a lookup table as each flight number is normally dedicated to a particular route and as such repeating them in this table is unnecessary duplication. For example you seem to be going to 'Sidney,' but really you are going to 'Sidney' (no comma) so a query for all flights going to Sidney is going to find QF431. 
Another reason for removing them is that as it stands the QF431 departure and destination airports could change between rows which could violate the rule that each flight number is unique to a flight path. With the current structure this rule could not be enforced by the dbms

Comment: Cheers for the help, I'll try implementing your suggestions